# c# Cannot implicitly convert type System.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader to system.data.sqlclient.sqldatadapter

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

It Says I Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader` to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter`:

[image: It Says I Cannot implicitly convert type System.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader to system.data.sqlclient.sqldatadapter]

Comment: Please edit your question and copy/paste your code as text, according to the rules of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is correct.

Replace the lines with:

```
con.Open();

var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

itms.Load(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually meant to use a `SqlDataReader` rather like

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
            var connstr = db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection connection;
            connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = null;
            DataTable tab = new DataTable();

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select Query from [Drag-Drop] where [User_ID] = '" + UserID + "' order by Clock desc", connection);
            adapter.Fill(tab);
            string DQuery = tab.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Let me know, if helps :)